# How to decode base64 to GIF in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gif, animated-gif

I have a python flask-restful API, I am trying to add the feature to allow users to upload GIFs, the client will upload a base64-encoded GIF to the API for that, so on the API I need to be able to decode base64 to GIF and also be able to do operations on it such as resizing and compression then convert it to bytes

I tried to do with PIL like this:

```py
img_bytes = BytesIO()
# I specified the duration to be 67 because I want the GIF to play at 15 FPS, 1000 / 15 = 66.66
self.image.save(img_bytes, append_images=self.frames[1:], format=self.format, save_all=True,
                optimize=False, duration=67, loop=0)
img_bytes.seek(0)
```

The problem with that implementation is that I find a lot of distortion and black pixels in the GIFs and inconsistent framerate/animation speed, it's overall pretty bad and it makes a 75 KBs GIF be 1.8 MBs, any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. It works for me.

```
from PIL import Image
import base64
import os
myimagestring = "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"
myimagedata = base64.b64decode(myimagestring)
myimagefile= open("myimage.gif","wb")
myimagefile.write(myimagedata)
myimagefile.close()
myimageobject = PhotoImage(file="myimage.gif")
```

And here is a function to resize the image if needed:

```
from PIL import Image

def get_resized_img(img_path, picture_size):
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    width, height = picture_size  # these are the MAX dimensions
    picture_ratio = width / height
    img_ratio = img.size[0] / img.size[1]
    if picture_ratio >= 1:  # the picture is wide
        if img_ratio <= picture_ratio:  # image is not wide enough
            width_new = int(height * img_ratio)
            size_new = width_new, height
        else:  # image is wider than picture
            height_new = int(width / img_ratio)
            size_new = width, height_new
    else:  # the picture is tall
        if img_ratio >= picture_ratio:  # image is not tall enough
            height_new = int(width / img_ratio)
            size_new = width, height_new
        else:  # image is taller than picture
            width_new = int(height * img_ratio)
            size_new = width_new, height
    return img.resize(size_new, resample=Image.LANCZOS)
```

Comment: And how do I resize it?

Comment: @InfinityVive updated with the function you wanted

Comment: apparently, the resizing function turns it into a single-frame GIF, it only takes the first frame and drops the rest

Comment: it says name 'PhotoImage' is not defined